# Get Discriminator value in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am working on Hibernate project and I don't know how can I get value of the discriminator without adding another column?

```
<class name="gestion.commande.modele.Personne" table="personne" dynamic-update="true" lazy="false">
    <id name="identifiant" type="int" column="IDENTIFIANT">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="TYPE" type="string"/>
    <property name="nom" type="string" column="NOM" />

    <property name="prenom" type="string" column="PRENOM" />
    <property name="login" type="string" column="LOGIN" />
    <property name="password" type="string" column="PASSWORD" />


    <subclass name="gestion.commande.modele.Client" discriminator-value="client">
    <property name="adresse" type="string" column="ADRESSE" />

    <bag name="commandes" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key column="IDCLIENT" />
        <one-to-many class="gestion.commande.modele.Commande" />
    </bag>
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="gestion.commande.modele.Administrateur" discriminator-value="Administrateur" />

</class>
```

This is my Model:

```
public class Personne {

protected int identifiant;

protected String nom;

protected String prenom;

protected String login;

protected String password;

protected String type;



public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Personne() {

}

public Personne(String nom, String prenom, String login, String password,
        String type) {
    super();
    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
    this.type = type;
}

public Personne(String nom, String prenom) {

    this.nom = nom;
    this.prenom = prenom;
}   

public int getIdentifiant() {
    return identifiant;
}

public void setIdentifiant(int identifiant) {
    this.identifiant = identifiant;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

When I load Personne from database and I call getType it return `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the name of **discriminator** column like:

```
  <discriminator column="type" type="string"/>
```